# NUnit unit tests order or separate runner in TeamCity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

**Question:**

Can I use separate unit test runner for subgroup of unit tests in my build? All of those that would need separate runner process are contained within single .dll

Or at least is it possible to specify order of unit tests?

**Background:**

I have some unit tests that are testing integration with native components that makes the process memory dirty and so in production code I recycle my process after using them. (it's python integration for .net and some packages are not designed for python engine unload and reload).
However the unit tests are only isolated by app domains - so they still remain in same process and can colide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TestCategory] NUnit attribute to create different test group. After grouping, you could run only specific group from TeamCity server. You could also divide it into different steps.

But also as a variant, you could use [OneTimeSetUp] and [OneTimeTearDown] attributes.

Useful links:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx - description for TestCategory attribute.
2. http://nunit.org/docs/2.5/consoleCommandLine.html - how you can run your test categories from nunit-console.
3. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Getting+Started+with+NUnit#GettingStartedwithNUnit-Case1.CommandLine - how you could use nunit-console inside team city.

Second approach:

1. https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute
2. https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeTearDown-Attribute

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I use both options heavily - they are very helpful, but not in this particualr case (since I need to run all tests - not just selected categories and the initialization is not extracted from the code being tested - which would be good idea; but not justifiable to to touch legacy code).

However you pointed me in needed direction - there is a 'Run process per assembly' option that serves my purpose very well

Answer (score 0):

Turns out TeamCity supports separation of test assemblies by individual test runner processes - option called 'Run process per assembly' in NUnit build step configuration:

[image: Run process per assembly]

More details here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/NUnit (search 'Run process per assembly')